# razor cshtml javascript not reachable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to run javascript based on TempData that i pass from the controller.

But using the code below with razor, it neve reach to second if statement. I have a feeling that i am not using the proper razor syntax.

```
@if (TempData["status"] != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var status = "@TempData["status"]";
        if (status == "customerAdded") {
            swal("1!", "good", "success")               
        }
        else {  

        }            
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Did you get any console error? Please check your console log first. Then if you not get any error then simply put alert inside your script tag and check, does it popup or not?

Comment: @superted did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert TempData to String or else to check data value or you can use `console.log("-");` inside your javascript to check your code run or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Json.Encode` and `@Html.Raw` on your C# data to make it compatible with your scripts.

```
@if (TempData["status"] != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var status = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["status"]))'; // this is the change
        if (status == "customerAdded") {
            swal("1!", "good", "success")               
        }
        else {            
        }

    </script>
}
```